# Fantasy movie where princess puts soot on her face, leaves castle and has adventures

Tags: story-identification, movie, young-adult

Looking for a movie possibly using modelling clay or puppets to animate the characters. A young princess is told to put soot on her face, leaves her castle and has adventures among common people. The movie screened on SBS Australia around 1999 or 2000 in at least two parts. Possibly an animation of a folk story.

Comment: Were there any science fictional or fantastical elements to this story, or was it just a princess in blackface walking around?

Comment: Not "blackface." Soot to make herself dirty so as to appear to be one of the peasants.  There are several fairy tales like that.

Comment: A good point, though. Fantasy is often set in medieval Europe, but the two are distinct. Are there any magical or fairy-tale elements here?

Comment: Can @JRE remember the names of the fairy tales where soot is used to make the main character dirty to appear to be one of the peasants? This element stood out most from the story, the subsequent story is unclear after so many years. Yes, there were fairy-tale elements but no science fictional elements. As the movie was in more than one episode, it may have been a short series.

Comment: Can't think of any animated in that style.  Most of the fairy tales I've seen on TV were in German, so the titles wouldn't help if I could remember them - and they may not be known in English speaking places.

Answer (score 1):

[Allerleirauh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allerleirauh) or Princess Allerleirauh is the name of several fantasy movies adapted from a German Fairy Tale.

Allerleirauh means "All Kinds of Fur" or "Thousand Fur". the Princess covers her face with soot and wears an animal skin coat to escape from her father, the king, who has decided to marry her. Her fate is not what we would expect in modern story telling. Allerleirauh was made into movies and TV series in 1971, 1999, 2002, 2004, 2012 and 2014. YouTube has several versions.

Comment: Can you possibly provide the one that you were initially looking for? Which aired on SBS Australia?

Comment: There was apparently a version of the story on Jim Henson's live-action/puppet show [The Storyteller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Storyteller_(TV_series)#Sapsorrow) (1987) which could account for the puppets mentioned.  Looks like the puppets were only the animal helpers.  At 22 minutes, doubtful that it is multi-part, though.